# Access igraph R objects from Python

Tags: python, r, igraph

I have a graph object created with the **igraph *R* package**. 
If I understand the architecture of the **igraph *software* package** correctly the **igraph *R* package** is an interface to use `igraph` from `R`. Then since there is also a **igraph *Python* interface** I wonder if it is possible to access my `igraph object` created with `R` via `Python` directly. Or if the only way to access and `igraph R object` from `Python` is to export the `igraph R object` with `write.graph()` in `R` and then import it with the **igraph R package**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two interfaces use different data models to store the graph attributes, so I think there is no safe and sane way to access an igraph object in R from Python or vice versa, apart from saving it and then loading it back. Using the GraphML format is probably your safest bet as it preserves all the attributes that are basic data types (numbers and strings).